# Integration by Parts with a Jump Discontinuity

Tags: calculus

I ran into the following problem and its solution:

> The integration by parts formula
>   $$
> \int_{a}^{b}u\frac{dv}{dx}\,dx=uv\bigg|_{a}^{b}-\int_{a}^{b}v\frac{du}{dx}\,dx
> $$
>   is known to be valid for functions $u(x)$ and $v(x)$, which are continuous and have continuous first derivatives. However, we will assume that $u$, $v$, $du/dx$, and $dv/dx$ are continuous only for $a\leqslant x\leqslant c$ and $c\leqslant x \leqslant b$; we assume that all quantities may have a jump discontinuity at $x=c$.
>
> (a) Derive an expression for $\int_{a}^{b}u\,dv/dx\,dx$ in terms of $\int_{a}^{b}v\,du/dx\,dx$.
>   $$
> \int_{a}^{b}u\frac{dv}{dx}\,dx=uv\bigg|_{a}^{b}+uv\bigg|_{c^+}^{c^-}-\int_{a}^{b}v\frac{du}{dx}\,dx.
> $$

Could anyone clarify to me how this was obtained?

**Edit**: Following the advice of [Muphrid](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/45296/muphrid), I obtained the following:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{c^-}u\frac{dv}{dx}\,dx+\int_{c^+}^{b}u\frac{dv}{dx}\,dx&=uv\bigg|_{a}^{c^-}-\int_{a}^{c^-}v\frac{du}{dx}\,dx+uv\bigg|_{c^+}^{b}-\int_{c^+}^{b}v\frac{du}{dx}\,dx,\\
\int_{a}^{b}u\frac{dv}{dx}\,dx&=\color{red}{uv\bigg|_{a}^{c^-}+uv\bigg|_{c^+}^{b}}-\int_{a}^{b}v\frac{du}{dx}\,dx.
\end{align}$$

What is the rule for combining the terms in red?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In response to your work from Muphrid:

$$\begin{align} 
\color{red}{uv\bigg|_{a}^{c^-}+uv\bigg|_{c^+}^{b}} &= uv(c^-) - uv(a) + uv(b) - uv(c^+) \\
&= uv(c^-) - uv(c^+) + uv(b) - uv(a) \\
&= uv\bigg|_{c^+}^{c^-} +uv\bigg|^b_a
\end{align}$$

Comment: I am sorry; I changed the limits of integration after you saw my edit, but your derivation follows exactly the same way. Thank you!

Comment: I see that now, and went ahead and fixed my answer. Best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using the usual integration by parts formula on the separate intervals $[a,c)$ and $(c, b]$ and then putting the two results together.

Answer (score -1):

Corrected based on comment.

Consider the example
$$ \int_{0}^2 x \, H(x-1) \; dx, $$
where $H(x)$ is the unit step function. Modifying the limits to account for $H(x-1)$ gives
$$ \int_{0}^2 x \, H(x-1) \; dx= \int_{1}^2 x \; dx = \frac{4}{2} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2} $$

Applying standard integration by parts with $v = \frac{x^2}{2}$ and $u = H(x-1)$ gives the correct answer
$$ \int_{0}^2 x \, H(x-1) \; dx= \frac{x^2}{2} H(x-1) \bigg|_{0}^2 - \int_{0}^2 \frac{x^2}{2} \delta(x-1) \; dx = \frac{4}{2} - 0 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2}. $$

Since $u$ has a jump at $c=1$, the modified result proposed in this question would not capture the $-\frac{1}{2}$ from the delta function and instead get the same value from
$$ \frac{x^2}{2} H(x-1) \bigg|_{1^+}^{1^-} = -\frac{1}{2}. $$

Comment: Both approaches are correct. you cannot apply delta function and split interval atr the same time